# My breadcrumb does not align with the search bar using Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see in this example, my breadcrumb does not align like my search bar, I want it to be at the left-middle of the red background (just like the search bar). I'm using Bootstrap to do so.

Here is my code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="background-color: red;">
        <div class="row marginTop">
            
            <div class="col-md-4 ">
                <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                  <ol class="breadcrumb bg-dark"><!--transparent-->
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item "><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Test2</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Test3</a></li>
                  </ol>
                </nav>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-4 ml-auto my-auto" style="background-color: black;">
                <form class="d-flex">
                    <input class="form-control mr-1" type="search" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn_rechercher" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>     
            </div>

        </div>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Cordially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apdate your HTML with following code

```
<div class="col-md-4 pl-0">
   <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
     <ol class="breadcrumb my-2 bg-dark"><!--transparent-->
       <li class="breadcrumb-item "><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
       <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Test2</a></li>
       <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Test3</a></li>
     </ol>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: That put the element at the center thanks. But do you know how to put it to the left please (without the red background to be seen) ?

Comment: Code is updated by adding ```pl-0``` to the parent column